# AFImageRequestOperation wait until finished

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, afnetworking

i have a little problem with this, I'm loading an Image from a Url like this:

```
+ (void)getImageFromURL:(NSString *)imageFilename urlMode:(NSString *)mode block:(id (^)(UIImage *responseImage))aImage {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[mainURL stringByAppendingString:mode]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    AFImageRequestOperation *requestOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                              imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                                                                         cacheName:nil
                                                                                           success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) 
                                          {
                                              aImage(image);
                                          }
                                                                                           failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                          {
                                              // manage errors
                                          }];
    [[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] addOperation:requestOperation];
}
```

I'm trying to set an iVar UIImage *userAvatar to the response from this request, but the problem is, since its an async request I'm not getting the iVar set before my Code moves on, so my iVar is empty when I'm accessing it and passing it to another method.

Answer (score 2):

That's the nature of asynchronous programming!  You are going to have to redesign the dependencies on `userAvatar` to take into account that it's availability is nondeterministic.

So, rather than having your operation's success block simply set the `userAvatar` ivar, it takes care of whatever needs to happen once that image is available.  For example if you want to set a `UIImageView`'s image, then in your success block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    myImageView.image = image;
});
```

*(Without knowing the details of your goals and details of your implementation, this is just a "for example...")*

Comment: Hmm, let me try to explain, I'm having a LoginView there i put my login data, if login is success I'm passing the response from the request to my model to handle the user creation, the model passes the user back to the LoginView and the LoginView passes the user to the UserView and the LoginView gets dismissed. And it gets dismissed before the image is set to its value. And there's my problem.

Comment: Ah.  So, since you pass the newly created user object between the `LoginView` and the `UserView`, couldn't you fetch the image asynchronously as a responsibility of the user object? Then, if you need to take some action in the UserView when the image is available, you could use KVO to trigger appropriate response when the user avatar image is set; so, for example, `UserView` would observe `self.user.userAvatar`

Comment: Oh, I assumed your user was a model object.

Comment: ok since i cannot post an answer with more explanation here is a link to a pastebin there is the Model code and beneath is the call to the model and the delegate call http://pastebin.com/XnyXCrVm

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `[requestOperation start];` at the end.